# Error message from ModelState.AddModelError() doesn't appear

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

My program has users who can create a project (which behave like folders) and inside the projects the user can add documents.
The user can than share the project with another user.

I have prevented that a user can add the same person twice in the same project but I can't seem to display the error message I want.

The email has Required attributes and those error messages appear (both if it is invalid and if the box is empty).

Am I not using the ModelState.AddErrorMessage() right?

This is how the variable is in the Model

```
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a valid email address!")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter an email!")]
    public string email { get; set; }
```

This is a part of my Controller

```
//Prevent double share
List<ProjectModel> userProjects = projectService.getAllProjects(user.email);
    foreach(var proj in userProjects)
    {
        if(proj.name == userService.getProjectByID(urlInt).name)
        {
            //This is the error message I am trying to display
            ModelState.AddModelError(user.email, "This user already has access to this project!");
            return View(user);
        }
    }
userService.share(user.email, urlInt);
return RedirectToAction("../Dashboard/Dashboard");
```

This is my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Share", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "add-document-form" }))
{ 
    <div class="add-document-div">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email address</label>
            <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email, new { @class = "form-conrtol" })
            <br />

            <!--Here is the validation for the email button-->
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-fab" value="Send invitation" />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload for [`ModelState.AddModelError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError%28System.String,System.String%29) that you're using takes two parameters; the **name** of the model property to add the error to, and the actual error. You need to make sure that the first parameter is the correct name. In this case, I'd assume `"email"`.

Currently, you're giving it whatever `user.email` contains, rather than the field name.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response!
I changed the `user.email` to `"email"` which is the name of the variable but the message still doesn't show.
Any idea why?

Comment: The `""` empty string does get overriden with the AddModelError

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't seem to work, maybe it isn't overwriting the validations which are given in the model. Maybe I need to think of another approach.
Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: It works now! I posted my answer below, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for

```
ModelState.AddErrorModel("<some form field name>", "<your error message>");
```

The first parameter is the form field name so that mvc knows where to bind the error message.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(user.email, "This user already has access to this project!");
```

is trying to bind the error message to whatever the value of user.email is.  This does not exist in your form.

Answer (score 0):

To add errors via the controller for server-side validation you just need to provide the key name in string format.. so in your case this should work:

```
ModelState.AddErrorModel("email", "This user already has access to this project!");
return View(user);
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response! I changed the `user.email` to `"email"` which is the name of the variable but the message still doesn't show. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have a line in your form that's like this: `@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just needed to change `user.email` to `"email"` like was already pointed out.

The reason why that didn't work for me at the time was because another person was cleaning up our ServiceBase and broke my connection to the database so my form wasn't posting at all.

After I fixed that the error message shows.

Thanks for your help everybody!